# How to get the query parameters in Iron-router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to get the query parameters in the url.

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this...

which leaves me with the feeling that I must have missed a something in the doc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**iron router >= 1.0**

A route's [query parameters](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router#query-parameters) are available as properties of `this.params.query`.

If your URL looked like:

```
/posts/5?sort_by=created_at
```

then `this.params.query.sort_by` would equal `'created_at'`.

---

**iron router < 1.0**

A route's query parameters are available as properties of `this.params`.

If your URL looked like:

```
/posts/5?sort_by=created_at
```

then `this.params.sort_by` would equal `'created_at'`.

Comment: I thought that too but the query parameters are not showing up in the this.params

Comment: It should work, try using this debug hook Router.onBeforeAction(function(){console.log(this.params);}); and typing any URL with query parameters to access your app, you'll see them in the console.

Comment: @saimeunt - as I said, this.params is empty

Comment: @pat It would be really helpful if you could update your question with a simplified version of the URL and the route.

Comment: it turns out that this.params.sort_by is set but the javascript console does not show it when doing this.params by itself

Comment: In the console it shows params as an Array of 0 length yet you can expand it and see that it has the queries set as properties. I'm not sure if you can iterate over the params without knowing what they are.

Comment: This is now this.params.query.sort_by in Iron Router v1.0.

Comment: Since this answer is no longer right, can we shift the correct answer?

Answer (score 45):

Just call

`Router.current().params //params is the dict you wanted`

in Iron Router 7.1+

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 24):

Interestingly three answers and no one offered the complete answer.

**Iron-Router 1.0.x**

From within a route, use:

```
// URL: http://example.com/page/?myquerykey=true
this.params.query   // returns the full query object
this.params.query.myquerykey   // returns a particular query value
```

Similarly, outside of the route (but still inside the client code), and inside your template, use:

```
// URL: http://example.com/page/?myquerykey=true
Router.current().params.query
Router.current().params.query.myquerykey
```

Query parameters, not to be confused with parameters passed via the URL.

Comment: well done, this should be accepted as the correct, and complete, answer.

Comment: Good Answer in case you want to get the values in Template Helpers, specially when you want to get the query values outside the route

Answer (score 17):

In Iron Router 1.0.0, you need to use

```
this.params.query.YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME
```

to get it

For example, if you route is /xxx/?a=b

```
this.params.query.a
```

outputs 'b'

Answer (score 2):

try tihs:

```
 Router.current().params.parametername;
```

and in router.js file routing must be:

```
route(routername/:parametername)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that if you are using Router.go that your first parameter is a template name, and not a path. query parameters are not passed if you specify a path.

Answer (score 1):

**Encoded URI undefined Solution:**

The better way to get the query parameters object is:

```
this.request.query.MyParam
```

Using the suggested option of:

```
this.params.query.MyParam
```

Is ok as long as you are not working with encodedURI parameters, when using this option with encodedURI parameter, the parameter will be equal to undefined.

Example below:

```
{ // console.log(this.params.query)
    product: 'Chair',
    ip: '172.0.1.183',
    message: 'My Little Chair',
    request: '100% Discount',
    severity: '4',
    api_key: 'XXXXX' 
}

{ // console.log(this.params.query)
    product: 'Chair',
    ip: '172.0.1.183',
    message: 'My Little Chair',
    request: 'undefined', // NOTICE THIS CHANGED TO UNDEFINED!
    severity: '4',
    api_key: 'XXXXX' 
}

Original Query String:
?product=Chair&ip=172.0.1.183&message=My Little Chair&request=100%25%20Discount&severity=4&api_key=XXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass queries like this depending on where you accessing the router:

In the **template**

```
{{pathFor 'routeName' query='queryName=queryValue'}}
```

In the **helper**

```
Router.go ('routeName',{},{query: 'queryName=queryValue'}
```

Note: the empty object between the `routeName` and the query is if you want to specify any parameters (refer to the full docs to see the difference).

If you would like to pass multiple queries do it like this:

```
query: 'queryName1=queryValue&queryName2=queryValue'
```

Don't use spaces and remember to use the `&` sign.