# getting some part of URL

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to get the end part of this URL **(in the sever side)**:

```
http://localhost:3000/insAds/D79htZY8DQ3YmcscE
```

I mean I want to get this string:

```
D79htZY8DQ3YmcscE
```

there is a similar question: [How to get the query parameters in Iron-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050664/how-to-get-the-query-parameters-in-iron-router)

but non of the answers can't help me! because I have no query params in the URL.

I know these codes gives me the string that I want:

```
this.params.id
```

and

```
Router.current().params.id
```

but these codes works only in client side! I want to get that string in the server side!

finally I'm trying to get that string and use here:

```
Ads.before.insert(function(userId, doc) {
    //console.log(this.params.id);
    doc._categoryId = this.params.id;
    doc.createdAt = new Date();
    doc.createdBy = Meteor.userId();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Router.current().params` or `this.params` like this

```
Router.route('/insAds/:id', function () {
    console.log(this.params.id); // this should log D79htZY8DQ3YmcscE in console
});
```

Check the third example in Quick Start section of [iron router documentation](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router#quick-start)

**EDIT:** Based on our chat,

Your hook is

```
Ads.before.insert(function(userId, doc) {
    //console.log(this.params.id);
    doc._categoryId = this.params.id;
    doc.createdAt = new Date();
    doc.createdBy = Meteor.userId();
});
```

Change it to

```
Ads.before.insert(function(userId, doc) {
    doc.createdAt = new Date();
    doc.createdBy = Meteor.userId();
});
```

And then define meteor method in server like this

```
Meteor.methods({
    'myInsertMethod': function (id) {
         Ads.insert({
             _categoryId: id
         });
    }
});
```

Call this from client side like this

```
Meteor.call('myInsertMethod', Router.params().id, function (err, res) { 
    console.log (err, res);
});
```

Comment: I want to get that string in server side. `Router.current().params` works only in client side. I have this bug with your answer: **has no method 'current'**

Comment: @Roohollah Can you give us a sample code or context in which this is needed so that I may suggest solving the problem in a different way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105910/discussion-between-roohollah-and-kishor).